# Looking for a way to hide parameters in a jenkins pipeline job until a referenced parameter is chosen

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The issue I'm trying to solve is how slow the page is to load when I click build with parameters. The parameter list is very large and the page takes forever to load them all at once. I'm wondering if there is a way to have each parameter appear after the parameter before it has been chosen by the user.